# Чи є калькою вираз "зробити пропозицію" в сенсі запропонувати одружитися?

Tags: from-russian

В перекладеному кіно (чи кіні) постійно чуємо "зробив мені пропозицію", що мені здається калькуванням російського "сделать предложение", яке в свою чергу бере початок від довшої фрази "сделать предложение руки и сердца", що в українському варіанті із пропозицією звучало б досить кострубато: "зробив мені пропозицію руки і серця", бо вираз "запропонувати руку" є архаїчним (як свідчить СУМ у статті ["Запропонувати"](http://sum.in.ua/s/zaproponuvaty)), а слово пропозиція видається мені доволі модерним (можливо через те, що є явнішим запозиченням, аніж "пропонувати").

Чи правильно мені здається, що "зробити пропозицію" не є властивим українській мові, а є калькою? Якщо так, то які суто українські відповідники російської фрази "он сделал мне предложение" існують, або може варто завжди перекладати як "від запропонував мені одружитися"?

Answer (score 5):

Суто українські відповідники: **І.** **Засилати (присилати) старостів (сватів) (за рушниками)**, **ІІ.** **освідчуватися**, **ІІІ.** **Пропонувати руку й серце.**

**І.** [СВАТ 1](http://sum.in.ua/s/svat), а, чол.

> **Засилати (заслати, посилати, послати, слати і т. ін.) сватів** — те саме, що **Засилати (заслати) старостів (див. засилати)**. *Гарні в
>   колгоспі дівчата, Будем весілля гуляти, Хлопці, ви часу не гайте,
>   Також сватів засилайте* (Любов Забашта, Квіт.., 1960, 97); *Звичаю
>   посилати сватів тепер майже не дотримуються — молоді люди, які
>   вирішили одружитися, обходяться без їхніх послуг* (Народна творчість
>   та етнографія, 6, 1968, 47); *Отож послав Михайло сватів; дівчата вже
>   в дружки прибираються та міркують, яке-то весілля в Наталі буде*
>   (Марко Вовчок, I, 1955, 96)

[ЗАСИЛАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/zasylaty), аю, аєш, недок., ЗАСЛАТИ, зашлю, зашлеш, док., перех.

> **Засилати (заслати) старостів** — **посилати старостів до дівчини, жінки або її батьків, просячи згоди на шлюб.** *Зачали парубки
>   засилати старостів до дівчат* (Квітка-Основ'яненко, II, 1956, 65);
>   *Настя йому сподобалась, і становий заслав до неї старостів* (Нечуй-Левицький, III, 1956, 251).

[ПРИСИЛАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/prysylaty), аю, аєш, недок.,

> **Присилати (прислати) старостів (сватів); Присилати (прислати) (людей) за рушниками** — те саме, що Засилати (заслати) старостів
>   (див. засилати). *Шепелява Марія зістарілась, посивіла, бо Гнат не
>   присилав старостів* (Казки Буковини. Казки Верховини, 1968, 29);
>   *Родичі переказали, що Лукіян Середа згоден віддати за Грицька дочку — «нехай присилає сватів»*. І Грицько наважився нарешті (Андрій Головко,
>   II, 1957, 513); — *Попроси, щоб сьогодні, або хоч завтра, нехай
>   присила [сотник] людей за рушниками, а у неділю і весілля*
>   (Квітка-Основ'яненко, II, 1956, 207).

**ІІ.** [Освідчуватися](http://sum.in.ua/s/osvidchuvatysja) (як доповнення до значення *`признаватися в коханні`*, та й то це більше раніше *`освідчуватися`* означало відразу і *`признатися в коханні`*, і *`просити згоди стати дружиною`*. Зараз же можна скільки завгодно освідчуватися, та й не женитися :)).

> 2. **Просити у жінки згоди стати дружиною.** — Я, мамо, з Манею Обринською оженюся. Я їй уже освідчився (Ольга Кобилянська, III, 1956,
>      236).

Але, як на мене, обидва зазначені варіанти на сьогоднішній день втрачають свою актуальність з огляду на сучасні особливості процесу, надто в містах. У селах ще подекуди зберігаються традиції, хоча теж більше формально.

Нейтральним може бути **ІІІ.**[Пропонувати руку й серце](http://sum.in.ua/s/proponuvaty) (хоча СУМ подає це значення, як *застаріле*)

> **Пропонувати руку [і (й) серце]** кому, заст. — **просити кого-небудь стати своєю дружиною.** *Стаха мала хлопців більше, ніж пальців на
>   обох руках, а проте ніхто з них не пропонував їй свою руку* (Ірина
>   Вільде, Сестри.., 1958, 386); *Без кінця, без кінця Пропонує руку. А
>   що любить — ні слівця, Про любов — ні звуку* (Олександр Підсуха,
>   Жарти.., 1968, 78).

І хоч мережа рясніє варіантом **`зробити пропозицію руки й серця`**, мені здається, що **`(за)пропонувати руку й серце`** - милозвучніше для означеного контексту, бо **`робити пропозицію`**, як на мене, тяжіє до офіційного (ділового) стилю.

Цю тезу підтверджує [Російсько-український словник сталих словосполучень](http://ros-ukr-idioms.wikidot.com/d)

> **делать, сделать предложение кому** а) (предлагать что-либо) робити, зробити пропозицію, пропонувати, запропонувати кому; б) (*просить
>   стать женой*) **пропонувати, запропонувати руку [й серце],
>   освідчуватися, освідчитися кому**.

Comment: Є ще розмовне _звати заміж_. Найбільш [гендерно]нейтральне і найменш поетичне буде _запропонувати одружитися_.

Answer (score 2):

[Російсько-український народний сучасний словник](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) пропонує наступні варіанти перекладу:

> сделать предложение кому – освідчитися кому, посвататися до когось,
>   запропонувати кому одружитись, зробити пропозицію про одруження кому;
>   (через сватов) послатися до кого;

Однак згідно з СУМом, то "[посилатися](http://sum.in.ua/s/posylatysja)" - це застарілий варіант, хоч і можливий:

> 3. заст., розм. Посилати старостів, свататися до кого-небудь. Посилався до дівчини, та не сподобався (Словник Грінченка).

[Російсько-український словник сталих виразів 1959р.](https://r2u.org.ua/html/vyrgan_pered.html) (І. О. Вирган, М. М. Пилинська):

> Сделать предложение кому – освідчитися кому; зробити пропозицію про
>   одруження кому; запропонувати кому одружитися [з собою]; посвататися
>   до кого.

Якщо ми говоримо про переклад "предложение руки и сердца", то можна перекласти як "сватання", "освідчення" або "освідчини",

Answer (score -2):

краще - "освідчитись"))) як мені здається

Comment: Ласкаво просимо на сайт Ukrainian Language.SE! Цей допис не відповідає нашим стандартам якості. «Здається» кожному з нас по-своєму, і це може бути лише суб'єктивною думкою, але не  відповіддю. Як мінімум, треба пояснити причини, чому саме це слово є правильним, а також надати посилання на поважні джерела. Також, перегляньте, будь ласка, [tour], там написано про загальні правила хороших запитань і відповідей.